# What is a Kaizala Action? Is it open for 3rd party developers?

Tags: kaizala, kaizala-action

I am pretty new to Kaizala and would like to understand about Kaizala action and if its APIs are exposed for 3rd party developers.

Comment: Is this related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620710/can-we-use-the-existing-actions-cards-which-are-already-there-in-kaizala-app) that you posted earlier today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaizala Actions are basic 'units of work' that help users get work done within a conversation context inside Kaizala. Some of these Actions like Job, Survey, Poll, etc. are shipped out-of-the-box and provide scoped functionality. These Actions can be discovered within the Kaizala app and can be invoked in a conversation context from the Action Palette. [Read more](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/kaizala-docs/blob/master/Articles/actions.md).

Kaizala supports development of custom Actions and is currently **under preview** state. We are trying out different functionalities with our limited partners and customers. If you want to try out custom Action capabilities and be a part of our development community, reach out to kaizalaDev@microsoft.com

Kaizala has publicly available REST APIs to let 3rd party systems integrate with Kaizala.