# Can we use the Existing Actions Cards which are already there in kaizala app?

Tags: kaizala, kaizala-action

Can we use the Existing Actions Cards which are already there in kaizala app or we have to create our own custom card? If so, then please help me to create custom action to fetch data and send data using API to app using Kaizala existing actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use available **out-of-the-box** Kaizala Actions. They include:

1. Announcement - make key announcements or share updates
2. Job - assign jobs to people and track completion status
3. Let's Meet - invite people to meetings and confirm their availability status
4. Live Location - request live location and help people find their way
5. Photo with Location - share a picture with your current location
6. Quick Poll - ask a question and get people’s opinion
7. Request Location - request people to share their location
8. Share Location - share your location with others
9. Submit Bill - submit your bills and expenses
10. Survey - ask a series of questions and get people's opinions
11. Checklist - create to-do lists and capture everyone’s status

If these Actions do not suffice your requirements, you can also build **custom Kaizala Actions** for your needs. However, development of custom Actions is under **preview mode** and we are testing it out with our limited partners/customers. If you want to try out development of custom Actions, please feel free to reach out to kaizalaDev@microsoft.com

We will help you out with your requirements of fetching data through API within custom Actions, once you reach out. However we have publicly available [REST APIs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/kaizala-docs/blob/master/Articles/connectors/API.md) to let your systems integrate with Kaizala.